# Cronjob is working in my computer but not on the host server

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, web-scraping, localhost

I have a python program which extracts data and saves it in the database

I am using cron tab on my local computer as follows which works fine!

```
15 20 * * * python /home/ahmed/Dropbox/AppFlatForRent.py
```

Now i am using a similar command on my hostserver but it doesnt work

```
15 20 * * * python /home/AppFlatForRent.py
```

When I run the `python /home/AppFlatForRent.py`independently, it works perfectly (since i am getting values in the host's database)

What is wrong with the cronjob command? I have also tried this but doesnt work

```
/usr/bin/python /home/AppFlatForRent.py
```

Comment: Which OS is this? Did you check the syslogs (name depends on your OS)?

Comment: Can you have a look at /var/log/syslog and /var/log/cron* (off the top of my head) and see what's actually happening?